# check two strings have the same numbers of characters and the same character occurrences Python

Tags: python, string, substring, comparison

I have the following strings, and I need to check if both have the same numbers of characters (I do it with len) and the same character occurrences (I do not know how to do it). I can't use collections or sort; it must be a function. I have tried to resolve with set but it doesn't work.

For s1 and s2 I have to obtain True
For s3 and s4 I have to obtain False

s1 = "aabbcc", s2 = "abcabc", s3 = "aab", s4 = "abb"

This is my function (doesn't work for s3 and s4)
Can anyone help me?

```py
def check(s3,s4):

    if len(s3) == len(s4) and set(s3)== set(s4):
        print (True)
    else:
        print (False)

check(s3,s4)
```

Comment: "I can't use collections or sort; it must be a function." Please clarify this constraint; if it is from an exercise, quote it. Can you use a function that *uses* `collections`? How about the `sorted` *function*? Which functions or modules are you allowed to use?

Comment: FWIW, `if condition: print(True)` can just be `print(condition)`

Comment: Also, please explain what *"same character occurrences"* exactly means, as it is ambigious.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the occurrence of each character on your own (using a dict comprehension) and compare afterwards:

```
def check(a,b):
    res = []
    
    for item in (a,b):
        chars = set(item)
        res.append({c: item.count(c) for c in chars})
    return res[0] == res[1]

s1 = "aabbcc"
s2 = "abcabc"
s3 = "aab"
s4 = "abb"

print(check(s1,s2))
print(check(s3,s4))
```

Out:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another wayto do that

```
s1 = "aabbcc"
s2 = "abcabc"
s3 = "aab"
s4 = "abb"

def check(s1, s2):
    return {c: s1.count(c) for c in set(s1)} == {c: s2.count(c) for c in set(s2)}

print(check(s1, s2))
print(check(s3, s4))
```

### OUTPUT

```
True
False
```